# Spring mvc RestTemplate postForObject doesn't send parameter to REST API

Tags: spring, rest, post, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have a REST API. I'm making a client.
I configured spring security to authentication by my rest service. 
My REST API controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="content-type=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
UserDetails loginUser(WebRequest request)
        throws LoginOrPasswordException {
    logger.info("login user");
    logger.info(request);
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    logger.info(username);
    UserDetails uDetails = userRepository.login(username);
    System.out.println(uDetails.getPassword());
    return uDetails;
}
```

Application context of API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.zayats." />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Http Json MessageConverter -->
<bean id="jsonConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>

<import resource="jdbc-config.xml" />
```

Next is client method with restTemplate

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("username", username);
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(params, requestHeaders);
    logger.info("Create map and doing request.");
    UserDetails matchingUser = restTemplate.postForObject(
            "http://localhost:8080/ApiFamilyShoplist/user/login", httpEntity,
            UserDetails.class);
```

Rest Template config

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean id="jsonConverter"
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I call my API with postForObject in controller of API doesn't receive any parameters.
Please, give me some advice how to make it to send data to API.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have another parameter in your method to accept the string parameter and annotate it with  `@RequestBody` (inside the method signature):

```
@ResponseBody
@Consumes("text/plain")
public UserDetails loginUser(WebRequest request, @RequestBody String userName)
```

Also, if you're passing a string, I suggest to add a simple http string converter to the converters of the rest template and annotate the server method with `@Consumes(text/plain)`. This way you'll get it as a simple string.

Comment: `@RequestBody` in what method? In API controller?

Comment: @user2391060 You are trying to get request parameter (POST or GET), however you are posting JSON. There will be not parameter on HttpServletRequest entity. So you need to tell Spring that it needs to convert the request body to JSON object. `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params` should be parameter of your controller method.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with sending JSON... suggesting to use string is quite a radical solution. For string you can just use request parameters.

Comment: Also what @PavelHoral said would work. But instead of getting a simple string, you'll get a map of keys (parameters names) that map to objects (the actual parameters). If I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Avi - just a guess that Jackson is able to unmarshall into `Map<String, Object>`. If not, a different class will be needed (e.g. `ObjectNode`)

Comment: @PavelHoral - Not always you want to user request params. I'm talking from my own experience. We had a large string that included i18n (different languages) characters. It's not something you pass in the url.

But I agree that for a lot of cases the url is enough

Comment: @PavelHoral - You're right about the unmarshall into `Map<String, Object`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it in 30 minutes. But follow your words I'll have to `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params` in all methods to receive any data from client?

Comment: Usually, if you pass an object and you have a class to represent such object in the server (Let's say - call `User`) you can do something like:

`public void method(@RequestBody User user)` And you'll get the actual object already converted from string.

In you case you just pass a string so such map is enough I guess.

Comment: But if I'm trying to send, for example `List<String>` what should I do?

Comment: Generics are problematic in this case. As far as I know the best solution would be using `String[]` instead.

Comment: `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params` is working. Great thanks to all.:)